# HashMap ArrayList to TextView

Tags: android, arraylist, android-sqlite

I am retrieving value from `SQLite` Database, I have a method which is getting data from database and returning it in a `ArrayList` of `Hashmap` generic. 
But I don't know how to take that data from HashMap to Textview. I have 2 textviews.

This is method for getting data.

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Getdetails(){
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    //String sem="'First'";
    //try{
    SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this).getReadableDatabase();


    String query = "SELECT * FROM tutorial WHERE name='"+item+"'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("desc", cursor.getString(2));

            userList.add(user);
        }
    }

    // }
    //catch (Exception e){
    //  Toast.makeText(this, "Error "+selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //}
    return  userList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get HashMap from Arraylist then get value from HashMap.

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrDetails = Getdetails();
    HashMap<String, String> hashDetails = arrDetails.get(0); // Use this index accordingly
    textView1.setText(hashDetails.get("name")); 
    textView2.setText(hashDetails.get("desc"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your calling Method:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> details = Getdetails();
HashMap<String, String> user = details.get(0); // If it contains only one key value
nameTextView.setText(user.get("name"));
descriptionTextView.setText(user.get("desc"));
```

I would create final static fields for "name" and "desc" and think about using naming Conventions